# Сложная выборка телефонных номеров из БД

Tags: sql, postgresql

СУБД `postgresql 9.4`

Допустим в таблице есть такие данные

```
date                 number_a     number_b     seconds
-------------------  -----------  -----------  -------
2019-05-01 00:17:01  70000000001  70000000002  100
2019-05-01 00:17:11  70000000001  70000000003  75
2019-05-01 00:17:30  70000000001  70000000004  90
2019-05-01 00:17:51  70000000001  70000000005  120
2019-05-01 00:17:59  80000000001  80000000005  100
2019-05-01 00:18:10  45000000001  44444000005  250
2019-05-01 00:18:19  45000000001  66666660005  300
2019-05-01 00:18:55  55550000001  70000000005  100
```

где

`date` - начало звонка

`number_a` - номер А

`number_b` - номер Б

`seconds` - продолжительность звонка в секундах

Звонок от номера А на номер Б не закончился, но начинается звонок опять от номера А теперь на другой номер Б, за одинаковую дату.

Можно ли отловить всех номеров А которые попадают под это условие, и показать количество таких звонков от него, т.е.

```
date       number_a     count
-------    -----------  -----
2019-05-01 70000000001  4
2019-05-01 45000000001  2
```

Если можно то как реализовать данный запрос

Comment: *Можно ли* Если данные позволяют - то можно. *и показать количество таких звонков от него, т.е.* Синхронизируйте показанные исходные данные и результат - сейчас они не соответствуют друг другу.

Comment: @Akina Если можно то как реализовать данный запрос ?

Comment: Сначала исправьте пример исходных данных и конечного результата, чтобы было ВИДНО, что должно получиться, и было ПОНЯТНО, как это соотносится с описанным алгоритмом подсчёта.

Comment: @Akina вот исправил, и думаю что понятно

Comment: Теперь поясняйте, что есть требуемое "количество звонков". Количество уникальных по (date,number_a) звонков, которые пересекаются хотя бы с одним другим звонком для той же пары, но с другим number_b? или number_b не учитывать? В исходных данных Вы должны показать ВСЕ ВОЗМОЖНЫЕ сочетания, и как именно они учитываются.

Comment: @Akina  Количество уникальных по (date,number_a) звонков и `number_b не учитывать`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение для PostgreSQL версии 9.4:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
  cte1 AS (SELECT number_a num, 
                  date ds, 
                  date + make_interval(0,0,0,0,0,0,seconds) df, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number_a ORDER BY date) rn
           FROM calls)            
, cte2 AS (SELECT t1.num, t1.ds, t1.df, t1.rn, t1.rn rnf
           FROM cte1 t1
           WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM cte1 t2 
                             WHERE t1.num = t2.num
                             AND t1.rn = t2.rn + 1
                             AND t1.ds <= t2.df
                             AND t2.ds <= t1.df)
           UNION ALL           
           SELECT cte2.num, LEAST(cte1.ds, cte2.ds) ds, GREATEST(cte1.df, cte2.df) df, cte2.rn, cte1.rn
           FROM cte1, cte2
           WHERE cte2.num = cte1.num
           AND cte2.rnf = cte1.rn - 1
           AND cte1.ds <= cte2.df
           AND cte2.ds <= cte1.df)           
, cte3 AS (SELECT num, rn, MAX(rnf) rnf
           FROM cte2
           WHERE rn != rnf
           GROUP BY num, rn)
, cte4 AS (SELECT num, MIN(rn) rn, rnf
           FROM cte3
           GROUP BY num, rnf)
SELECT num, SUM(rnf - rn + 1) cnt
FROM cte4
GROUP BY num;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qKhaTRfej1hqju1ZxsBZLs/2)

Comment: А для `postgresql 9.4` версии как будет

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком порядке PostgreSQL применяет GROUP BY и DISTINCT?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов DISTINCT применяется после GROUP BY и HAVING, непосредственно перед ORDER BY.

Comment: @Akina ругается `Query Error: error: syntax error at or near "t2"`
Не могу понять в чем причина

Comment: @Akina спасибо за ответ, при этих исходный данных все нормально, но как только я изменил длительность одного звонка то данные не корректно вышли, допустим строку `2019-05-01 00:17:11  70000000001  70000000003  75` изменил, т.е. 75 на 5 поменял и теперь  кол-во найденный номеров  увеличилось с 4 до 9, а должно было уменьшится на 3.

Comment: @Xfirab Ну вроде всё учёл... проверьте. Сделал три группы от одного номера, с разными выпендронами.

Comment: @Akina все подошло спасибо большое Вам

Answer (score 0):

1. Пишем подзапрос, в котором будет также содержать время окончания звонка.
2. Соединяем два таких подзапроса, по условию, что

   1. Совпадает номер
   2. Периоды звонка пересекаются
   3. Правый начался позже
3. Группируем по номеру и времени начала с подсчетом количества (count(*))
4. Группируем результат по номеру с поиском максимума из найденных на прошлом шаге количеств.

Comment: А как это реализовать в SQL ?

Comment: 1) Зачем? это вычисляется непосредственно в запросе. 2) Зачем два, когда есть CTE? 2.1) Какой номер? в каждой записи их два... 3) ... и плюс один 4) Почему максимум? почему не суммировать? впрочем, в задании это не уточняется.

Comment: 1) чтобы вывести для самоконтроля. Не во всех диалектах SQL увеличение даты на заданное кол-во секунд делается тривиально. 2) CTE - это тоже подзапрос. 2.1) искомый номер. 3) да, +1 4) ну да, неточность условия.

Comment: *CTE - это тоже подзапрос.* Это немножко не так. См. напр. https://habr.com/ru/company/postgrespro/blog/451344/